# Optimal Control and Dynamic Programming Principle

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I am looking at the dynamic programming principle in optimal control problems. I am reading a book on the subject. This is the statement of the problem and approach. The books is "Non-Cooperative Stochastic Differential Game Theory of Generalized Markov Jump Linear Systems" Cheng-Ke Zhang et. al.

The dynamics is given by,

$\dot{x} = f(t, x, u), \ x(0) = x_0$

We are trying to optimize a PI.

$\underset{u}{\min} \left[ \int_0^T g(x, x(s), u(s)) ds + q(x, T) \right]$

where $u$ are admissible controls.

The dynamic programming principle (Chapter 2, section 2.1.1 Dynamic Programming).

> The dynamic programming principle can be stated as follows (pg. 18).
>
> "A set of controls $u^*(t) = \phi^*(t,x)$ constitutes an optimal
> control solution to the control problem stated above, if there exists
> a continuous differentiable functions $V(t,x)$ defined on $[0,T]
> > \times \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and satisfying the Bellman
> equation,
>
> $-V_t(t,x) = \underset{u}{\min} \left[ g(t, x, y, u) + V_x(t,x) f(t,
> > x, u) \right]$ $= \left[ g(t, x, y, \phi*(t,x)) + V_x(t,x) f(t, x,
> > \phi^*(t,x)) \right]$   $V(T,x) = q(x)$"

The proof goes as follows,

$V = \underset{u}{min} \left[ \int_0^T g(s, x(s), u(s)) ds + q(x,T) \right]$, satisfying the boundary condition $V(T, x^*(T)) = q(x^*(T))$, and $\dot{x}^*(s) = f(x, x^*(s), \phi^*(s, x^*(s)), \  x^*(0) = x_0$. Consider another set of strategies $u(s) \in \mathcal{U}_m$, with corresponding trajectories $x(s)$, then from the bellman condition we have,

$g(t, x, u) + V_x(t, x) f(t, x, u) + V_t(t, x) \ge g(t, x^*, u^*) + V_{x^*}(t, x^*) f(t, x^*, u^*) + V_t(t, x^*)$

Now the book claims that integrating by parts produces the following result,
$\int_0^T g(s, x(s) ds + V(T, x(T)) - V(t_0, x_0) \ge \int_0^T g(s, x^*(s), u^*(s)) ds + V(T, x^*(T)) - V(t_0, x_0)$

The question is how did we get to this result? Integrating the $V_x$ term we have,
$\int_0^T V_x(s, x) f(s, x, u) ds = \int_0^T V_x(s, x) \frac{d x}{d s} ds = \int_0^T V_x(s,x) dx = V(T, x(T)) - V(0, x_0)$

We ge a similar term from the integral $\int_0^T V_s(s, x) ds = V(T, x(T)) - V(0, x_0)$. What am I missing? When you put it all together we end up with,

$\int_0^T g(s, x(s) ds + 2V(T, x(T)) - 2V(t_0, x_0) \ge \int_0^T g(s, x^*(s), u^*(s)) ds + 2 V(T, x^*(T)) - 2 V(t_0, x_0)$

Thank you in advance for all the responses.

Comment: 1. Please proof-read your question and [edit] it to correct all errors.  2. We require you to credit the original source of all material originally written by others.  Please provide a proper citation for the book, including title, authors, when published, and what parts you are quoting from.  Please indicate what parts are quoted by using proper quote marks (`> ...`) in Markdown.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: What errors do you see, I did proof read it.

Comment: Please check the title of your post.  Please specify what part of the book you are copying from (e.g., section/chapters numbers).  Please indicate what parts of your post are quotes, using quote marks (`> ...` or "...").

Comment: What about the title? I am not sure what exactly you want me to do. You want the chapters in the title?

Comment: I have corrected the title for you.  Please make two changes.  1. Edit the post to list the chapter numbers.  2. Edit the post to mark which parts are quoted from the book, by using Markdown block quotes.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes.

Comment: I have already added the chapter and section. I got the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out the answer. The answer is pretty straight forward. Here it goes.

$g(t, x, u) + V_x(t,x) f(t,x,u) + V_t(t,x) = g(t,x,u) + V_x(t,x) \dot{x} + V_t(t,x) = g(t,x,u) + dV(t,x)$

where

$dV(t,x) = V_x \dot{x} + V_t$